# Terraformer | The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to import a few AWS resources using terraformer.

`terraformer import aws --resources lambda --filter Type=lambda;Name=lambda-function-name`

But I am getting the following error:

```
aws importing... lambda
aws error initializing resources in service lambda, err: operation error Lambda: ListFunctions, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: some-request-id, api 
error UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the request is invalid.
aws Connecting...
```

My provider configuration is as follows:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.16"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.2.0"
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "ca-central-1"
}
```

I thought this might be related to incorrect aws credentials.
But I am able to use `aws cli` successfully in the same terminal window.
I am also able to use `terraform plan` and `terraform apply` successfully.
This makes me think that this might be related to terraformer.
I am using terraformer with version v0.8.22